# Type sharing in OCaml - typechecker error

Tags: module, functional-programming, ocaml, functor

When compiling this program:

```
module type Inc =
    sig
        type t
        val inc : t -> t
    end

module type Dec = 
    sig
        type t
        val dec : t -> t
    end

module Merger (I : Inc) (D : Dec with type t = I.t) =
    struct
        let merge x = x |> I.inc |> D.dec
    end

module IntInc : Inc = 
    struct
        type t = int
        let inc x = x + 10
    end

module IntDec : Dec = 
    struct 
        type t = int
        let dec x = x - 8
    end

module Combiner = Merger (IntInc) (IntDec)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "simple.ml", line 30, characters 35-41:
Error: Signature mismatch:
       Modules do not match:
         sig type t = IntDec.t val dec : t -> t end
       is not included in
         sig type t = IntInc.t val dec : t -> t end
       Type declarations do not match:
         type t = IntDec.t
       is not included in
         type t = IntInc.t
       File "simple.ml", line 13, characters 38-50: Expected declaration
       File "simple.ml", line 9, characters 13-14: Actual declaration
```

I thought that `D : Dec with type t = I.t` constraint will ensure that `D.t = I.t`. Why it is not so?

What is more interesting, when I remove `module Combiner = Merger (IntInc) (IntDec)` line it compiles without errors.

My question is : What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of `Merger` with the constraint is perfectly correct, which is why that part compiles without error.

As you said, the only part that doesn't compile is `module Combiner = Merger (IntInc) (IntDec)`. This is because, as far as OCaml knows, the constraint `IntInt.t = IntDec.t` is not met. The reason for that is that OCaml does not know that `IntInt.t` and `IntDec.t` are `int`. All it knows is that `IntInt : Inc` and `IntDec : Dec` - everything else is a private detail of the module.

To fix this problem you can change the module's headers to `IntInt : (Inc with type t = int)` and `IntDec : (Dec with type t = int)`, making the type `t` a part of the modules' public interface rather than a private detail, allowing OCaml to use that information when resolving the constraint of the `Merger` functor.