# How to merge OCaml module types (signatures) defining the same type?

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, I have two module types defining a type `t`:

```
module type Asig = sig
    type t
    val a : t
end

module type Bsig = sig
    type t
    val b : t
end
```

I want to automate the creation of a module type merging them. I want to create a module type equivalent to:

```
module type ABsig_manual = sig
    type t
    val a : t
    val b : t
end
```

I tried

```
module type ABsig = sig
    include Asig
    include Bsig
end
```

but this fails with `Error: Multiple definition of the type name t`. It seems impossible to add a type constraint to the `include` so I'm stuck.

Context: I have a module `AB` that does implement both signatures and I want to feed it to a functor like:

```
module MakeC(AB) = struct
    type t = AB.t list
    let c = [AB.a; AB.b]
end

module C = MakeC(AB)
```

I could use two arguments like in:

```
module UglyMakeC(A : Asig)(B : Bsig with type t = A.t) = struct
    type t = A.t list
    let c = [A.a; B.b]
end

module C = UglyMakeC(AB)(AB)
```

but this (is ugly and) doesn't scale well to more functors or more signatures to merge.

So, *how can I automate merging those two module types?* I can modify A and B as needed but I want to keep them separated. Also, maybe my approach is completely wrong, and in that case I'd love pointers to a better direction.

[Type sharing in OCaml - typechecker error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27295630/905845) is related but merges modules, not module types.

Comment: Did you consider asking on the `caml-list@inria.fr` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the way to do it :

```
module type Asig = sig
    type t
    val a : t
end

module type Bsig = sig
    type t
    val b : t
end

module type ABsig = sig
    include Asig
    include Bsig with type t := t
end
```

It's called "destructive substitution".

Comment: For future reference, this is documented in "Language extensions", paragraph "Substituting inside a signature" (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec234), which extends what's described in "The OCaml Language", paragraph "Module types" (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modtypes.html).

Comment: More durable link to reference: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.07/extn.html#sec249 (secXXX anchors in ref manual are modified for each new version of OCaml)

Comment: Real World OCaml (pp. 186-187) proposes an alternative solution to this type of situation, explaining "[t]his is somewhat cleaner when combining multiple interfaces, since it correctly reflects that all of the signatures are being handled equivalently":

`module type ABsig = sig
    type t
    include Asig with type t := t
    include Bsig with type t := t
end`